# Python: Replace ith occurence of x with ith element in list

Tags: python, string, replace, loops, substitution

Suppose we have a string `a = "01000111000011"` with `n=5 "1"`s. The *ith* `"1"`, I would like to replace with the *ith* character in `"ORANGE"`.
My result should look like:

```
b = "0O000RAN0000GE"
```

What could be the finest way to solve this problem in Python? Is it possible to bind an index to each substitution?

Many thanks!
Helga

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tons of answers/ways to do it.  Mine uses a fundamental assumption that your #of 1s is equal to the length of the word you are subsituting.

```
a = "01000111000011"
a = a.replace("1", "%s")
b = "ORANGE"
print a % tuple(b)
```

Or the pythonic 1 liner ;)

```
print "01000111000011".replace("1", "%s") % tuple("ORANGE")
```

Answer (score 5):

```
a = '01000111000011'
for char in 'ORANGE':
  a = a.replace('1', char, 1)
```

Or:

```
b = iter('ORANGE')
a = ''.join(next(b) if i == '1' else i for i in '01000111000011')
```

Or:

```
import re
a = re.sub('1', lambda x, b=iter('ORANGE'): b.next(), '01000111000011')
```

Comment: The first part of this answer, while clear, has horrible performance.  It should not be used if this task needs to be done for more than one string.

Comment: The second part of this answer will have problems if there are more 1's in the original string than in the replacement characters (try the solution with '010001110000110101010101').

Answer (score 3):

```
s_iter = iter("ORANGE")
"".join(next(s_iter) if c == "1" else c for c in "01000111000011")
```

Comment: This answer will have problems if there are more 1's in the original string than in the replacement characters (try the solution with '010001110000110101010101').

Answer (score 0):

If the number of 1's in your source string doesn't match the length of your replacement string you can use this solution:

```
def helper(source, replacement):
    i = 0
    for c in source:
        if c == '1' and i < len(replacement):
            yield replacement[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            yield c

a = '010001110001101010101'
b = 'ORANGE'
a = ''.join(helper(a, b)) # => '0O000RAN000GE01010101'
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving on bluepnume's solution:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, repeat
>>> b = chain('ORANGE', repeat(None))
>>> a = ''.join((next(b) or c) if c == '1' else c for c in '010001110000110101')
>>> a
'0O000RAN0000GE0101'
```

[EDIT]

Or even simpler:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, repeat
>>> b = chain('ORANGE', repeat('1'))
>>> a = ''.join(next(b) if c == '1' else c for c in '010001110000110101')
>>> a
'0O000RAN0000GE0101'
```

[EDIT] #2

Also this works:

```
import re
>>> r = 'ORANGE'
>>> s = '010001110000110101'
>>> re.sub('1', lambda _,c=iter(r):next(c), s, len(r))
'0O000RAN0000GE0101'
```